# Google Adwords API integration (V201708/V201710) with Code Igniter 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, google-ads-api

For Google adwords API I've used [this library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib) and It's working fine alone. But I am unable to integrate this library with CI 2.x.

Some code snippet is :

```
    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    define('SRC_PATH', APPPATH.'/third_party/Adwords/src/');
    define('COMMON_PATH', 'Google/AdsApi/Common/');
    define('ADWORDS_PATH', 'Google/AdsApi/AdWords/');
    define('ADWORDS_VERSION', 'v201710');

    // Configure include path
    ini_set('include_path', implode(array(
        ini_get('include_path'), PATH_SEPARATOR, SRC_PATH))
      );

    // Include the AdWordsUser file


    require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/AdWordsSessionBuilder.php';
    require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/Reporting/v201710/DownloadFormat.php';
    require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/Reporting/v201710/ReportDefinition.php';
    require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/Reporting/v201710/ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.php';
    require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/Reporting/v201710/ReportDownloader.php';
   require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/ReportSettingsBuilder.php';
   require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/v201710/cm/Predicate.php';
   require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/v201710/cm/PredicateOperator.php';
   require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/v201710/cm/ReportDefinitionReportType.php';
   require_once SRC_PATH.ADWORDS_PATH. '/v201710/cm/Selector.php';
   require_once SRC_PATH.COMMON_PATH. '/OAuth2TokenBuilder.php';


    class My_adwords {
    }
```

Getting following fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsBuilder' not found in /var/www/html/crm2017/application/third_party/Adwords/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/AdWordsSessionBuilder.php on line 38
```

Please suggest some optimum solution.

Comment: You should use composer instead, 2 second install vs n*days figuring out what needs what..

Comment: Yes, I used composer for normal and work fine but unable to run composer with Codeignitor 2.x. My main concern is integration with Codeignitor 2.x.

Comment: Why would you have issues with it :/ are you saying because it not included? Or have you tried something which didnt work? Just install it, run the install cmd for the lib and include the autoloader..

Comment: have codeigniter too, and no problems found with composer in it. Maybe try it again and ask a new question if you still find no solution

Comment: Error file downloaded when I open error-path in browser...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
//namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201710\Reporting;
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    require __DIR__ . '/../third_party/Googleadwords/googleads-php-lib/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201710\ReportDownloader;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201710\DownloadFormat;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettingsBuilder;
    use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;    
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\ReportDefinitionService;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\CampaignCriterionService;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Predicate;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\PredicateOperator;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Paging;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Selector;     
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\BiddingStrategyConfiguration;
    use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\BiddingStrategyType;

class My_adwords {
    public function __construct() { 
     //$oAuth2Credential = new OAuth2TokenBuilder();
    }

 function GetCampaignsCost() {
   // Get the service, which loads the required classes.
   $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->build();

    // See: AdWordsSessionBuilder for setting a client customer ID that is
    // different from that specified in your adsapi_php.ini file.
    // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the OAuth2
    // credentials above.
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();

    $reportFormat = DownloadFormat::CSV;
    $reportQuery = 'SELECT Cost,CampaignId,BiddingStrategyType,CampaignName FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY';

    // Download report as a string.
    $reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
    $reportSettingsOverride = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())
        ->includeZeroImpressions(false)
        ->build();
    $reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReportWithAwql(
        $reportQuery, $reportFormat, $reportSettingsOverride);
    $data = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
}
}
```

I've used **use** instead of require_once. Just include library once and use class which needs. I've done following steps:

1. Composer runs outside of CodeIgnitor and all dependencies adjusted
   via composer and put same folder inside application/third_party.
2. Make a class inside application/library which interact with
   third_party. Above snippet belongs to library class.
3. Load library in controller and call function of library.

Hence Solved.